# How can I loosely couple UserStore with IdentityUser?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an IUserBusinessLogic class that I want to inherit from IUserStore
IUserStore is part of Identity.Core, and it takes in a generic of TUser where TUser is an IUser.

My IUserModel is an IUser.

I would like to inherit from EntityFramework's implementation like so:

```
UserBL : UserStore<IUserModel>
```

But EntityFramework's UserStore is tightly coupled to IdentityUser.

```
public class UserStore<TUser> : IUserLoginStore<TUser>, 
    IUserClaimStore<TUser>, IUserRoleStore<TUser>, IUserPasswordStore<TUser>, IUserSecurityStampStore<TUser>, 
    IUserStore<TUser>, IDisposable 
where TUser : IdentityUser
```

This is a problem for me because my business layer and model layer aren't referenced, they only interact through interfaces. My implementation of IUserModel inherits from IdentityUser but UserStore explicitly wants an IdentityUser.

Any Ideas?